# mythbuntu epg cron job not working

Tags: cron, mythbuntu

I've got a problem with my EPG grabber script 'shepherd' for the Australian EPG. These two commands below work when I type it as user mythserver but when I put them in cron the first command creates a file of zero length:

```
# Collect data
18 13 * * * mythserver        /usr/bin/tv_grab_au --notimetest --output /home/mythserver/.mythtv/farm2.xmltv

# Read in data
30 4  * * * mythserver        /usr/bin/mythfilldatabase --file 1 /home/mythserver/.mythtv/farm2.xmltv
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you put the commands into the crontab manually? I believe shepherd can do this for you. If you do - which user's crontab do you use?

Comment: I'm putting them in manually because the automatic ones are not working and these are the work around commands. I've tried putting these into the users crontab using 'crontab -e' (without defining the user), but currently I have these two commands in my main /etc/crontab file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to enable cron logging and see what exactly is happening. Googling finds the following [instructions](http://www.casualcode.com/2008/05/18/how-to-enable-cron-log-in-ubuntu/) on enabling cron logging:

> edit /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf (uncomment the line starting with #cron.* - remove the # )
>
> restart cron - sudo service rsyslog restart

I think the most likely cause of the problem is permissions although I don't see anything suspicious in your crontab